# Blue Red Swapped on HDMI

Tags: video

Connected to my TV with HDMI the Raspberry Pi swaps the Blue and Red channels - which gives me a nice purple 'gooseberry' logo but makes watching movies a little surreal.

This happens even with the command prompt. Is my HW faulty or is there some setting I missed?

TV is a no-name 720p LCD, in an NTSC country.

Comment: Is it possible your HDMI cable has them swapped over?

Comment: Same cable + same TV works with cable box

Answer (score 1):

The TV advertises itself as 1366x768 on the HDMI info but the colour only works properly if you set the output to 1280x720

Just for anybody else searching for similar issues